# Connecting 4-pin RGB led

Tags: led

Ok, I feel like this question is a bit underqualified for this site but I couldn't find anything better. Anyways. I have almost no knowledge about electronics, so sorry for the stupidity.

I want to connect several RGB LEDs with a 3 way switch (state 1, state 2, off) so that on state 1 the LEDs are blue and on state 2 they are orange. I basicly don't know how to control the LEDs. How would I solder it together? I know that I need resistors, they shouldn't be the problem though.

My powersupply would be a 3V Battery.

EDIT: [These](https://smile.amazon.de/50pcs-Common-Kathode-4-polige-Diode/dp/B07911J8M6/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=led-diode+rgb&qid=1554098797&s=industrial&sr=1-2) are the LEDs, 
I couldn't find any more info on them.

Comment: Most RGB LEDs have a common anode (+) or common cathode (-). Which have you got? Can you link to the datasheet? There's an edit link below your question.

Comment: You will only need to activate the blue LED for the blue color, I suppose. For orange, you will need some red and green and perhaps no blue at all. How much red and how much green is a matter of your own judgement. You can use different resistors to arrange this. By the way, a \$3\:\text{V}\$ power supply may not be able to supply the diode voltage needed by the blue LED. We need specs for the part you are considering. Ah! Common cathode, at least.

Comment: @jonk +1 and also use a resistor in series with the LED to limit current, otherwise your button cell will die real fast.

Comment: Your 4pin LED could also be the ws2812 type digital LED.  If this is the case you won't be able to get it to light up unless you inject proper digital control signal on in data-in pin.

Answer (score 3):

Wie gehts?

Looks like a common cathode arrangement. So let's assume that a \$3\:\text{V}\$ supply is sufficient for the purposes of all three LEDs, for now, and more forward.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdapZY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above schematic doesn't specify any of the resistor values. That is for you to work out. Just try some different values until you get what you want. \$R_3\$ is likely to be the smallest value resistor. But you can play with \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ to set various currents in their LEDs so that you get the *orange* color you desire.

Values for the resistors will be on the order of tens or hundreds of Ohms. None of them will be as high as being in the thousands, I suspect. But it's not hard to play with these values on a solderless breadboard to work out what gets the right orange color for you.